# transaction and logs order

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm building a blockchain game and in order to speed things up, I am also building a web application so users will read data from there.

so at first, I was thinking to listen to events and save their data on my DB, but then I read that the order of the events is not guaranteed,
then I thought maybe you use the transactionIndex and logIndex sort them and then put the data in the database but then I read that the order can also be changed.

is there a way to get events by the order they were mined on the block? the timeline of the data is very important, I cant have it mixed with older events

Answer (score 0):

You said the order can be changed, I think you may have met a block reorganization aka forked. You can try to save the data after a couple of blocks confirmnation.